# Openserver не запустился ни разу

Tags: openserver

Здравствуйте!

При нажатии на *Open Server x64.exe*, при первом запуске программы, выскакивает вместо красного флажка ошибка:

> Невозможно запускать одновременно несколько копий программы. Удалите лишние копий программы и повторите попытку!

Каюсь, несколько раз с ошибками устанавливал программу *Open Server*.
Оттуда и появились, наверное, эти копии? Но как их найти и удалить?

Comment: Попробуй перезагрузить комп. удалить папку openServer и почистить реестр и еще раз перезагрузить комп. а потом установить его еще раз. .... прога портабельна, в теории достаточно удалять только папку где он стоит

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте все Ваши диски на предмет наличия на них каталога *OpenServer*. Если он есть - просто удаляйте папку. Потом устанавливайте по новой. Каких-то более сложных действий наподобие запуска деинсталлятора или чистки реестра не требуется. OpenServer - это портативный комплекс, то есть он работает в своём контейнере и в операционной системе наследить не может. Конечно возможны и другие, более сложные проблемы, чем неудалённая старая папка. Но они проявляются при старте сервера, а не программного комплекса. Т.е. в случае других проблем ошибка будет другая, да и красный флажок появится, но в зелёный переключаться не будет.

Comment: Да, но при попытке удаления высвечивается "папка не может быть удалена, т.к. имеются открытые файлы..." Для IT-новичка - смертельный номер...

Comment: Перезагрузите комп, либо зайдите в диспетчер задач, и по удаляйте процессы связанные с опенсервером, и сможете удалить папку